# selectiong multiple radio buttons in a listview

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, listview, radio-button

In the code below there is the radio buttons which have the same name, however i still can select more than one button. Before i added the value and the runat="server" it worked fine, but i need the value and the runat for the code behind.

```
    <form id="rr" runat="server" action="" method="post">
<div style="max-width:600px;max-height:500px;overflow:auto">
<asp:ListView ID="BuyM" runat="server" DataKeyNames="kod" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table dir="rtl" style="border:1px solid black;background-color:#E6CCFF;" >
            <tr class="header">
                <td>sg</td>
                <td>dfg</td>
                <td>dfgdg</td>
                <td>dfg</td>
                <td>df</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></tr>
        </table>

    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="row">
            <th>
                   <input type="radio" id="rb" runat="server" name="rb" value='<%# Eval("kod") %>' />
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("kod") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("nameE") %>
            </th>
            <th>

                <%# Eval("Sk") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("groupN") %>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr class="alterRow">
            <th>
                <input type="radio" id="rb2" runat="server"  name="rb" value='<%# Eval("kod") %>'  />
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("kod") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("nameE") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("Sk") %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%# Eval("groupN") %>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        no records found
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView></div>
         <div style="width: 90px;margin-top:25px;">
         <asp:button id="register" runat="server" OnClick="register_Click" name="register" text="dfgd" Height="30px" Width="80px" /></div>
    </form>
```

code behind:

```
protected void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value="";

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in BuyM.Items)
    {
        var rd = item.FindControl("rb") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton;
        var rd2 = item.FindControl("rb2") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton;
        if (rd != null && rd.Checked)
        {
             value = rd.Value;
        }
        else if(rd2 != null && rd2.Checked)
        {
            value = rd2.Value;
        }
    }
    if (value != null || value != "")
    {
        Response.Write("value: " + value);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

is there a way to fix it with javascript or from the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the radio buttons to be asp:RadioButton and then use the 'OnCheckedChanged' event to disable / uncheck the other radio button. So something like:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("kod") %>' />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("kod") %>' />
```

In the code behind:

```
private void rb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(rb2.Checked) rb2.Checked = false;
}
```

Do something similar for rb2_CheckedChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Since radio groups are controlled in the browser have you checked if the name attributes are still valid after render? I know .NET will change / edit HTML attributes in some circumstances when running on server.